# How can I generate multiple graphs using a repeating simulation and plot all graphs on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I currently have a simulation like the following:

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)

count <- 1
BigList <- list()

repeat{

g <- erdos.renyi.game(30, 151 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("b", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("c", value = 0) 

V(g)$c <- sample(c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.15, 0.15, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1))

time <- 1
smallList <- list()

repeat {

mean <- mean(V(g)$a == 1)


V(g)$b <- sapply(V(g), function(x) { 
        NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ; 
        ifelse(length(NeighborList) > 0, 
        length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 1])/length(NeighborList),0) } )

V(g)$a[V(g)$c <= V(g)$b] <- 1

smallList[[time]] <- mean

mean2 <- mean(V(g)$a == 1)

time <- time + 1

if (mean == mean2) {
break
}
}

BigList[[count]] <- smallList
count <- count + 1

if(count == 51) {
break
}
}
```

So, this simulation runs 50 times, and each of the 50 times I want a graph that depicts the change in 'mean' over 'time'. Then, I want to add each generated graph to a single plot so I can compare the differences from each run. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: The loop never ends, probably because `count` never gets incremented. You have variables called `prop` and `prev_value` in your ggplot code, but I don't see those variables created anywhere in your loop. To plot each simulation in a single graph, save each simulation in a list, then convert the list to a data frame with a column marking the simulation number. Then use the simulation number as a group or colour aesthetic in ggplot2.

Comment: another option is using the `screen` functions. they can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/screen.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to not plot during the loop, but after using ggplot. For that you need to constructu a data.frame in your loop that contain all the data with a variable count. A row try would be to construct your datd frame this way

```
 df <- rbind(df,data.frame(time=time, prop=mean, count = count))
```

and in the end do

```
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=time, y=prop, group=count, colour = count)) +
       geom_line() + 
       geom_point()
```

You need to increment count somewhere. Use for loop if you can, and try to avoid at least names with ().